# Wrapper function for nlog - assigning log level

Tags: c#, nlog

I want to have a custom log class, which then injects its properties to nlog Logger. The class should initialize nlog target and config , and then others can use it without the need to know those details.

```
public interface ILogger
{
  void Log(LogEntry entry);
}

public enum LoggingEventType { Debug, Information, Warning, Error, Fatal};

public class LogEntry 
{

   public readonly LoggingEventType Level;
   public readonly string Message;
   public readonly Exception Ex;

   public LogEntry(LoggingEventType level, string message, Exception exception = null)
    {
      this.Level = severity;
      this.Message = message;
      this.Ex = exception;
    }
}


public static Main(){

   //Should happen in Class MyLogger that implements ILogger 

   var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
   var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") { FileName 
   "file.txt" };
   var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("logconsole");

   config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);

   NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;


  LogEntery log = new LogEntry( Error , "Bad stuff" , IOException);
  Logger nlog  = logger.Error( log.Ex , log.Message);
  //How can I inject log level to Nlog class Logger?
  }
```

How can I inject log level to Nlog class Logger?

Comment: I thought about that, but you cant assign Nlog.LogEvent value for a Logger object as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry about that, pressed enter too soon. 
Probably misunderstanding the question. The easy solution is to create Dictionary that maps from your own `LoggingEventType-enum` to `NLog.LogLevel`-values. The static dictionary can live on your own ILogger-implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
class NLogLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly NLog.Logger _logger;

    public NLogLogger(string name)
    {
        _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(name);
    }

    public void Log(LogEntry entry)
    {
        var nlogLevel = GetNLogLevel(entry.Level);
        if (_logger.IsEnabled(nlogLevel))
        {
           var nlogEvent = NLog.LogEventInfo.Create(nlogLevel, _logger.Name, entry.Message, entry.Ex);
           _logger.Log(typeof(NLogLogger), nlogEvent);
        }
    }

    NLog.LogLevel GetNLogLevel(LoggingEventType level)
    {
        switch (level)
        {
           case LoggingEventType.Debug: return NLog.LogLevel.Debug;
           case LoggingEventType.Information: return NLog.LogLevel.Info;
           case LoggingEventType.Warning: return NLog.LogLevel.Warn;
           case LoggingEventType.Error: return NLog.LogLevel.Error;
           case LoggingEventType.Fatal: return NLog.LogLevel.Fatal;
           default: return NLog.LogLevel.Trace;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for any syntax-errors.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Custom-extension-of-Logger-interface

Comment: Thanks! I thought about something similar but hoped there is a prettier way, because i'm new to nlog.

Comment: @LiadSagi If you have a pretty dream, then please show and tell. Maybe there are places where things can be improved to match your dream.