# Nlog configure Nlogviewertarget

Tags: nlog, nlog.config

I use **NLog** with target **Nlogviewer**. (Receiver is log2console)
Everything is configured with Configfile Nlog.config.

My problem: I can configure 
   includeSourceInfo="true"
This work as expected.

But the Stackframe that is used for this Info should skip 1 Frame.
This is possible to do in the Filelayout:

```
layout="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true}|${callsite:fileName=True:includeSourcePath=false:skipFrames=1}|${message}"
```

Here you can see the right info is written to the Logfile.
How to configure Nlogviewertarget to skip 1 `Stackframe`?

Comment: Work around is to move the unwanted source-code-path into its own assembly and call `NLog.LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(assembly)`

Comment: If the issue is the wrapping of NLog-Logger, then make use of `NLog.Logger.Log(Type wrapperType, LogEventInfo logEvent)`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Custom-extension-of-Logger-interface#custom-wrapper-and-callsite and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57834530/193178